# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to connect my java application with sql server 2012, but is giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
```

Can anyone can help me please?

Thank you very much.

Code of connection:

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.SQLException;


 public class CriaConexao {

 public static Connection getConexao()throws SQLException{
    try{

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://BRGDB:1433;database=DB_SQL;IntegratedSecurity=true";
            Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            return conexao;

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}  

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
    at sensores.forms.jTLoginConsulta.<init>(jTLoginConsulta.java:71)
    at sensores.forms.jTLoginConsulta$4.run(jTLoginConsulta.java:448)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

`jTLoginConsulta` imports:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.openide.util.Exceptions;
import sensores.basedados.CriaConexao;
import sensores.forms.jTMainMenu;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.*;
import sensores.basedados.CriaConexao;
import sensores.logica.Logins;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import sensores.logica.Alarmes;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
```

Line 71 where the error occurs:

```
68    public jTLoginConsulta() throws SQLException {
69          initComponents();
70        setIcon();
71      conexao=(Connection) CriaConexao.getConexao();
72    
73       }
```

Comment: Seems like you have the wrong import for Connection.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the right DB driver. Please show us your classpath.

Comment: I think you are using mysql-driver.jar instead of Microsoft SQL server driver jar file

Comment: Thank you all for reply, I edit my question, it helps?

Comment: Thank you all. Were all useful. Thank you @gtgaxiola

Comment: Thank you all. Were all useful. Thank you @Ray

Comment: Thank you all. Were all useful. Thank you @Octopus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the import for this Connection object

```
Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
```

it should be `java.sql.Connection`. It seems you have imported it wrongly `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`

**EDIT**

as per edited question:

```
 conexao=(Connection) CriaConexao.getConexao();
```

CriaConexo is returning the `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection` and you are casting it wrongly to `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`. Just correct the import to `java.sql.Connection` and remove the cast as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is almost sure that Sanjeev is right, but the problem Sanjeev is warning you about is not in your code.  Check `jTLoginConsulta.java`, there you will surely find that unnecessary `import` that is causing your problem

Comment: You have provided wrong class code in above question. your exception is `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
    at sensores.forms.jTLoginConsulta.<init>(jTLoginConsulta.java:71)` occurring in jTLoginConsulta class line:71. please post that as well

Comment: Here you go .. see at the Top most import. thats causing the problem, change it as mentioned in the answer and you should be good to go

Comment: I edited my question with all the data that I found important. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user3320956 see my last comment please

Comment: Very Thanks Sir. You save my life :)